# How would I go about creating an outbound firewall?

Tags: linux, firewall

Firewall being an overwhelming word, but I want all new connections to prompt a dialog where I can choose what happens to it, so that the correct nftable rules can be applied. Akin to open snitch but at this point it's so big I don't understand it's programming.

As a fun project I'd like to create it with python and nftables or eBPF, though it's very unclear on how to begin gathering the pieces. Any general ideas?

---

I'm proficient in networking, and python, but am looking at this from the perspective of a fun project. The biggest hurdle I have so far is I don't know how to redirect the syn packet to a python script where I could make further decisions.

Comment: A computer doing it's normal things will create hundreds of outbound connections just to load one complex web page. Do you really want to have to approve each of them, one by one?

Comment: Edit question to tell us, what your experience with net-filter-tables is? (is this the place to start, or do you already know all there is to know about them?)